# How can I add hyperlink to dropdown?

Tags: html, css

I need the button of dropdown to be a hyperlink in other word when click on the dropdown itself to take you to new page 
please see this code below:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will make things easier for those trying to help you and increase your chances of quickly getting a solution to your problem.

Comment: Try changing the <button> to an <a href="#"> tag

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using js.

```js
//get the select element
var select = document.querySelector('#myselect');
//registering event listener
select.addEventListener('change', select_change);

function select_change(event) {
   var url = event.target.value;
   window.location.href = url;
}
```

```html
<select id="myselect">
   <option value="https://google.com">Test</option>
   <option value="https://yahoo.com">Test 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I mean when I click dropdown Icon to take me to new page then to take me to link1 , link 2, link 3 thank you